# Dataframe and checcking the monotonic crescent of EventTime

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given the dataframe below, I would like to:

1. detect eventTime is not monotonic crescent (the difference between two consecutive value in sec should be < 0)
2. Any suggestion about how to solve it, by adding or subtracting x sec that is monotonic crescent?

Input DF:

```
  uuid,eventTime,Op.progress,Op.progressPercentage,AnotherAttribute
0,C0972765-8436-0000-0000-000000000000,2017-08-19T12:52:39,P,3.0,01:57:00
1,C0972765-8436-0000-0000-000000000000,2017-08-19T12:53:55,P,3.0,01:56:00
2,C0972765-8436-0000-0000-000000000000,2017-08-19T12:53:18,P,4.0,01:55:00
3,C0972765-8436-0000-0000-000000000000,2017-08-19T12:53:17,P,4.0,01:55:00
4,C0972765-8436-0000-0000-000000000000,2017-08-19T12:53:49,P,5.0,01:55:00
5,C0972765-8436-0000-0000-000000000000,2017-08-19T12:55:24,P,5.0,01:54:00
6,C0972765-8436-0000-0000-000000000000,2017-08-19T12:55:07,P,6.0,01:54:00
7,C0972765-8436-0000-0000-000000000000,2017-08-19T12:55:27,P,6.0,01:53:00
8,C0972765-8436-0000-0000-000000000000,2017-08-19T13:33:46,W,40.0,01:13:00
9,C0972765-8436-0000-0000-000000000000,2017-08-19T13:40:10,N,51.0,02:00:00
```

Output DF:

```
  uuid,eventTime,Op.progress,Op.progressPercentage,AnotherAttribute
0,C0972765-8436-0000-0000-000000000000,2017-08-19T12:52:39,P,3.0,01:57:00
1,C0972765-8436-0000-0000-000000000000,2017-08-19T12:53:28,P,3.0,01:56:00
2,C0972765-8436-0000-0000-000000000000,2017-08-19T12:53:48,P,4.0,01:55:00
3,C0972765-8436-0000-0000-000000000000,2017-08-19T12:54:35,P,4.0,01:55:00
4,C0972765-8436-0000-0000-000000000000,2017-08-19T12:55:05,P,5.0,01:55:00
5,C0972765-8436-0000-0000-000000000000,2017-08-19T12:55:24,P,5.0,01:54:00
6,C0972765-8436-0000-0000-000000000000,2017-08-19T12:55:17,P,6.0,01:54:00
7,C0972765-8436-0000-0000-000000000000,2017-08-19T12:55:27,P,6.0,01:53:00
8,C0972765-8436-0000-0000-000000000000,2017-08-19T13:33:46,W,40.0,01:13:00
9,C0972765-8436-0000-0000-000000000000,2017-08-19T13:40:10,N,51.0,02:00:00
```

The output has been generated by computing the distance in sec between the row0 and row6 and dividing it by 5 = number of rows that are not monotonic.

Comment: To be honest without knowing expected output its bit hard to play a guess game and answer the question.

Comment: Hi Bharath. Just add that details in the body of the problem.